# Chrome extension: content script to run on all pages, and another to only run on one page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that needs to do the following:

- inject a content script into the current (any) page when the popup fires
- inject a different content script into all pages of a specific domain, always

So far I have the first one implemented, by calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` in the `popup.html` file and having the following in the manifest to allow the script to run on any page:

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*"
],
```

Now, according to http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html, if I want a content script to always run on a specific page, I must declare it in the manifest and set permissions to include only pages that the code should run on. However, this will break the first part.

How do I solve this? The only way I can think of is to always call some kind of "caller" script which then does its own checking and loading of other scripts, but that just seems very messy, and i assume there *has* to be a better way.

Comment: thanks for fixing the tags! I was not aware that the latter one existed :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
{
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
     "tabs", "http://*/*"
  ]
}
```

`myscript.js` is automatically injected to google.com, you can still manually inject to `http://*/*`.

Comment: Quick follow-up question - `myscript.js` does not have access to the same localStorage as the rest of the extension. I really only want to run `myscript.js` if a particular option in the extension (stored in localStorage) is set... how would I do that?

Comment: @Mala You would need to send a request to background page, read localStorage there, and pass result back. See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html

Comment: awesome, thanks, got it working :) I only wish Firefox extensions were as easy to make

Comment: Extension messaging reference has moved to http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: There is documented an alternative for all pages & schemes
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
but I haven't got it working yet... :-(